# How to check NODE type in Bitcoin?

Tags: full-node, bitcoin-cli, pruning, node-services

There is a Bitcoin node in my Lab, how can I check it is a Full node or not? there is any command to check node type?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean to ask whether the node has the complete blockchain or is pruning.

Connect to the node and call `bitcoin-cli getnetworkinfo`, it tells you the version, and the “localservicenames”. If your node offers `NETWORK` and `NETWORK_LIMITED` it has the full blockchain. If it only offers `NETWORK_LIMITED`, but not `NETWORK` it is a pruning node.

If it is a very old version, you may need to use a different command, you can find documentation of the RPC commands here: https://bitcoincore.org/en/doc/